# how to get a handle on the UITableViewCell given NSIndexPath* iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, handle, nsindexpath

I have the indexPath of type NSIndexPath*,a reference to the tableView, I want to use these to get a handle on the corresponding cell.How dp I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But note that that method returns nil if corresponding row is not visible at the moment (or indexPath is out of the table's range)